How do I find the A_1 term?

R is 8 ohms.
For this circuit: at t = 0- the circuit's capacitor is an open circuit and the inductor is a short. i(0-) is therefore 0 since no current flows, while v(0-) is the voltage difference across the 40 ohm resistor (25 volts).
At t = 0+ the circuit is the 40 and 60 ohms in series with the capacitor (still at open circuit) and the inductor (still a short).
Alpha is 100 / (2 * 2.5) which is 20 s^-1
Omega 0 is 1/ sqrt(2.5 * 1 mF) which is also 20 s^-1, so the circuit is critically damped.
Therefore:
\$i(t) = (A_1 t + A_2)*e^{st}\$
S is just - alpha. Since initial current is 0 then A2 is 0. I'm struggling to find A_1.
I understand it will be a KVL, with the equation looking like;
\$-100 * i(t) + V_c(t) - V_L(t) = 0\$
Since i(0) is 0 and V_c(0) is 25 volts, then V_L(0) is 25 volts. Since the voltage across an inductor is the derivative of its current, times its inductance:
\$i_L '(0) = 25 volts / 2.5 Henries = 10 Amperes/Second\$
But:
\$i'(t) = A_1*e^{st} + s *(A_1 t + A_2)*e^{st}\$
\$i'(0) = A_1 + s *(A_2)\$
This suggests A_1 is equal to i'(0) (which is ten), but the answer is wrong.
Were did I make a mistake?

As you've concluded, this is a critically damped free response for a RLC series circut, where, for \$t \ge 0\$:
$$i(t) = A_1te^{-\frac{R}{2L}t} = A_1te^{-20t} \qquad [1]$$
$$\frac{di(t)}{dt}=A_1\left (e^{-20t}- 20te^{-20t}\right ) \qquad [2]$$
So
$$\frac{di(i)}{dt}|_{t = 0_+}=A_1 \qquad [3] $$
From KVL:
$$ -100i(t)-v_c(t)-2.5\frac{di(t)}{dt}=0 $$
Since \$i(0_+)=0 \space A\$ and \$v_c(0_+)=25 \space V\$:
$$\frac{di(i)}{dt}|_{t = 0_+}=-10 \space A/s$$
Then, from \$[3]\$:
$$A_1= -10 \space A/s$$
Replacing it in \$[1]\$ (for \$t \ge 0\$):
$$i(t)=-10te^{-20t}$$
The time (\$t=t_p\$) for the peak value (\$i=i_p\$) can be found by equating \$[2]\$ to zero:
$$ \begin{cases}
t_p = 0.05 \space s\\
\\
i_p \approx -0.184 \space A
\end{cases}
$$
A plot for \$i(t)\$:


For helping a "little", here is the behavior with microcap v12.
Note that V_L(0) is \$-25\$ V ... And \$i'_L(0) = -10\$ A/s.

